# MongoDB Return an array of years and months that have no documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB with documents that include the field `date: '2015-02-28'`. The date information is a string in the format `'yyyy-mm-dd'`. What I need to do is return an array of year-month strings that there are no documents for. So for instance if there were documents

```json
{_id: 001, date: '2022-01-01'}
{_id: 002, date: '2022-02-01'}
{_id: 003, date: '2022-04-22'}
{_id: 004, date: '2022-05-11'}
{_id: 005, date: '2022-06-01'}
{_id: 006, date: '2022-07-21'}
{_id: 007, date: '2022-08-08'}
{_id: 008, date: '2022-09-10'}
{_id: 009, date: '2022-11-09'}
{_id: 010, date: '2022-12-08'}
```

I need to make a call to the database that would return
`['2022-03','2022-10']`. The years will range from 2005 to the current year.

Comment: check the mongodb docs: `{createdAt:{$gte:ISODate("2021-01-01"),$lt:ISODate("2020-05-01"}}`

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/finding-data-between-two-dates-by-using-a-query-in-mongodb-charts/102506

Comment: instead of createdAt yours is date

Comment: @devin I don't see how greater than and less than would apply here.

Comment: It would return all the dates in the range that exist in the database, then to get the ones that don't exist simply process the data in your preferred language

Comment: Greater than one thing and less than something else means quite literally between.
Here is a simple example  want to get all numbers between 5 and 10:
I would do `(> 4 and < 11)` this would yield me `{5, 6,7,8,9,10}`

Comment: @Ido I know I could call for all the entries but there are thousands. It would be nice to avoid that using some of the MongoDB features like aggregation.

Comment: there is limit and there is also offset

Comment: `db.collectionName.find(<query>).limit(<number>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$range` to generate the year and month range arrays. `$unwind` the arrays to generate year-month tuples. Then, `$lookup` back to the collection to check for the existence of the record for that month.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      year: {
        "$range": [
          2005,
          {
            $add: [
              {
                $year: "$$NOW"
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      month: {
        $range: [
          1,
          13
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$year"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$month"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        year: "$year",
        month: "$month"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $set: {
            parsedDate: {
              $toDate: "$date"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$year",
                    {
                      $year: "$parsedDate"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$month",
                    {
                      $month: "$parsedDate"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "lookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$lookup",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              {
                "$dateFromParts": {
                  "year": "$year",
                  "month": "$month"
                }
              },
              "$$NOW"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VMB1TBstpQJ)

Comment: This worked for me! I will note that it took quite a while to discover that "from" in "$lookup" might be a different name if you are using mongoose. For instance my reference for the collection with Mongoose is "Show" but I had to use "shows" for it to work here.